# how can I concatenated string from a single list

Tags: python

I'm new in python, I was wondering how can I concatenate string starts with certain character (Eg.'g') in a list with the string after that. for example :

```
list = ['green', 'black', 'brown', 'yellow', 'red', 'pink', 'glow', 'big']
```

And the result I expected is :

```
new_list = ['green black', 'brown', 'yellow', 'red', 'pink', 'glow big']
```

Comment: Hello, please be sure to post any attempts you've made at solving this issue

Comment: an unrelated tip - don't name your lists "list", it's a saved word in python for the type list

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```py
lst = ['green', 'black', 'brown', 'yellow', 'red', 'pink', 'glow', 'big']

for i, j in enumerate(lst):
  if j.startswith('g'):
    lst[i] = f'{j} {lst[i+1]}'
    del lst[i+1]

print(lst)
```

Outputs:

```
['green black', 'brown', 'yellow', 'red', 'pink', 'glow big']
```

Tell me if its not working...

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
list = ['green', 'black', 'brown', 'yellow', 'red', 'pink', 'glow', 'big']
new_list = []
agrega = True
for i in range(len(list)):
    if agrega == False:
        agrega = True
        continue
        
    agrega = True

    if list[i].startswith('g'):
        new_list.append(list [i] + " " + list [i+1] )
        agrega = False
    else:
        if agrega:
            new_list.append(list[i])


print (new_list)
```

Comment: OP also wants to concatenate "glow" to "big" in the end (since "glow" starts with a G).

Comment: I corrected it now, thanks

Comment: use `is` not `==` for testing booleans. (it's faster, and `True` and `False` are singletons so it works). But in this case you don't care about being a strict boolean, so just use `if not agrega`